$m (E) <\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x)$ is bounded on $[a, b]-E$.

Let $\delta>0, \left\{\alpha_{k}\right\}$ be nonnegative numbers, $E_{k} \subset[a,  b],  m\left (E_{k}\right)  \geq\delta,  k=1, 2,  \ldots$ Suppose that  $$\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x) <\infty \ \ \text{a.e.}$$
where $\chi$ is the indicator function.
Prove $$\sum_{k} \alpha_{k}<\infty. $$
Hint: Choose $E \subset[a,  b] $,    such that $m (E) <\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x)$ is bounded on  $[a,  b]-E$.

How to find such an $E$ as specified in the hint above?
What I can see is just for some $k$, $$E=\bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$$ then $$[a,b]-E=\bigcap_{j=k}^\infty E_j^c$$ so that $$\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x) \leq k-1, x\in [a,b]-E.$$
But $m(E)\geq m(E_j)\geq \delta$.
What can be further suggested is the $x$ such that $x$ belongs to at most $k$ elements of $\{A_i\}$. Any hints?

Take $E=\{x: \sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x) >N\}$ If $N$ is large enough,  then $m(E) <\frac {\delta }2$ and $\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x) \le N$ on the complement of $E$.
Now $\int_{E^{c}} \sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x)dx \le N (b-a)$ because $\sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x) \le N$ on $E^{c}$. Also,  $m (E^{c}\cap E_k) \ge m(E_k)-m(E) > \delta -\delta /2=\frac \delta 2$. Finally, $N(b-a) \ge \int_{E^{c}} \sum_{k} \alpha_{k} \chi_{E_{k}} (x)dx=\sum_k\alpha_k m(E_k \cap E^{c})\ge \frac { \delta}2 \sum_k \alpha_k$.
